# R Equivalent to SAS EG Process Flow

Tags: r, sas, rstudio

I've just started a new role as a data analyst where I'll be using the RStudio IDE. In my previous role I had used SAS Enterprise Guide. I'm getting started with acquainting myself with R, not having used it much previously.

While I find RStudio reasonably user-friendly, I do miss the 'process flow' UI in SAS EG. In that vein, is there something like this for R that anyone could recommend?

Comment: What is the "'process flow' UI in SAS EG"? What does it do?

Comment: Essentially, it's a grid where scripts and the relationships between them are displayed: https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/guide/tut43/en/m15_1.htm

Comment: R doesn't have something like that. If you have a choice of tools, Knime may be a better option. It's also open source and free and a lot more like EG. @Roland a process flow looks like this: https://www.knime.com/knime-software/knime-analytics-platform

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Reeza, Knime does look quite appealing. I work for a large multinational where only 'endorsed software is readily available, but I'll see if getting this is possible. It's a shame there isn't an R IDE with this functionality; I think p

Comment: *I think people - especially those with more of a  business than programming background, find a process flow layout quite useful.

Comment: Unfortunately nobody has built that GUI.  I also miss it.